# Install docker on compute Canada

Tags: docker, cloud

I need to install docker on compute Canada but I have multiple problems. firstly, I do not have access so I cant use the sudo command. as a result, I can't follow docker documents to install docker by binary source.
Secondly, in compute Canada documents are mentioned that I should use ./configure to install new software but I get this error: -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

On ComputeCanada, like all shared HPC facilities, Docker is a joke.  We provide Singularity, which can do what Docker does (including use Dockerfiles).  We could also provide Podman, which is almost a pure/fixed Docker clone, and possibly a little easier to use than Singularity.

"./configure" is a common way to configure a package, but depends on the package providing such a script.  If it doesn't work, you are probably trying the command in the wrong location.  Most open-source packages do provide such a script in the base of their source tree, though some are simpler Makefile-based ones that just need "make".

You should simply open a support ticket for these issues, since none of them are new or novel.  support@computecanada.ca - and please provide as much information about what you're trying to do as possible.

I am ComputeCanada staff.  Feel free to email me as well (hahn@sharcnet.ca).

Comment: Do you mind explaining why Docker is a joke in HPC?

Comment: @Nahiyan: because it is designed for single-user desktops.  There's nothing wrong with the idea of containers, but podman demonstrates better container management without introducing security issues.